# Stop Windows Service to upgrade it by local user in c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

We have a c# .net framework 4.6 windows service installed from command line.There is no MSI.

The goal is the stop the service copy new exe in service folder and restart the service.
The Service was installed with admin privileges and run with local service account.
The app in charge of doing the update run as local user (not admin). This means that this app does not have privileges to stop or start the service.
The app can however communicate with the service and ask the service to do things.
So the app can ask the service to stop itself but the is no way to restart it after update.

A barbaric idea is to cause the service to crash itself. And do the update during the 60sec restart time set in the service properties.

What could be done in code to force the service to crash so it would trigger the recovery process. we have been trying to throw exceptions but nothing so far crash the service.
Any other suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Won't the app simply restart after a reboot?  Then force the user to restart the service after update.  Or run a .bat file which starts the service as admin.  Or login to the machine as admin and do the update.

Comment: Does the user have access to just kill the process? If it's an exe you will have a process running that you can kill using the Process class in .NET. Or can give the user permissions to stop the service, but you need admin to do that. If you want the user to be able to do things then give them access to do those things, otherwise require administrator.